# Traversing a Grid of N Cells without declaring 2 variables (rows and columns)

Tags: algorithm, graphics, grid, formula, bounds

I have been developing a game for canvas in JavaScript.

I have chosen to create the game without limitations to the world size grid.  So if they wish to play with a grid size of N, the logic will generate it.

I have been working with bounds detection and have begun to program a function that will change the cell location on the grid if the user decides to travel outside the screen.

For simplicity sake, I have shrunk the grid size to N = 9 so you can visualize this.  The grid looks like

```
    [0][1][2]
    [3][4][5]
    [6][7][8]
```

If the user is to travels off a -x value Cell[0], they will appear at the rightmost x position of cell [2].  this is represented as SQRT(N). So I know that the rightmost corner is SQRT(N).  I also know that N is the bottom right hand cell [8].

With that said, here is a sample of the cells and thier equation IDs.

```
   [0][1][SQRT(N)]
   [3][4][5]
   [N - SQRT(N)][7][N]
```

The grid above shows the x axis formulas for the 4 corners, but it is essential that I at least try to answer the inner cell equations before using static magic number switch-case conditionals.

here is some javscript code showing what I am explaining:

```
if (player.X < 0 - 10) {
    player.X = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    if (gameQuadrent == 0) {
        gameQuadrent = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(WORLD_SIZE));
    } else if (gameQuadrent == (WORLD_SIZE - Math.floor(Math.sqrt(WORLD_SIZE)))) {
        gameQuadrent = WORLD_SIZE;
    } else {
         gameQuadrent--;
    }
 }
```

Any more efficient ways of doing this?  I am trying to solve this problem without having to move over to a fixed world size.

Much Appreciated.

Comment: this will always limit you to squares --> would you have any interest in having rectangular worlds?

Comment: ok just read the title again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quadrent is on the left boundary of the world if it's number is a multiple of SQRT(WORLD_SIZE). Therefore the following code should update the gameQuadrent accordingly.

```
int side = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(WORLD_SIZE));
if (gameQuadrent % side) == 0) {
    gameQuadrent += side - 1;
}
else {
    --gameQuadrant;
}
```

Comment: This worked for the left side any thoughts on the right side? I cannot vote up based on restrictions on new users to stack overflow.  I appreciate your help sir, good day:)